# Can I change referrer for an iframe with browser extension?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, referrer

So the question in the title. Can I put my custom referrer for an iframe using chrome extension?

Comment: show us what you tried and what didnt work.

Comment: The coding process is going to be more time saving in future. I'm sure IDE will be able to provide you with ready to go snippets from resources such as stackoverflow. I didn't test any code at the time I asked the question and I didn't know where to start. So it took some time to find the answer. Do you remember times when on mostly every question you ask on forums, you received humiliating answers that you are not educated or diligent enough or whatsoever. This is already in the past. Web is going to be much more friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer and it is yes. This can be done with the `webRequest` API of chrome. Here is my snippet:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(details) {
    //check if we are going to url which referrer we want to change
    if (details.url.indexOf("targetUrl") != -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name.indexOf("Referer") != -1)
                details.requestHeaders[i].value = customReferrer;
            break;
        }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};

},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

`webRequest` API is available in `background.js` of the extension. In order to use `webRequest` and `blocking` specs you need to add proper declarations to the `permissions` field of your `manifest.json`.

More information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)